# OS X using Quartz event services to generate/simulate touch gestures: pinch, rotate, swipe, etc.

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, quartz-core

I'm trying to achieve simulation/generation of touch gesture events on OS X. I try something like this but it doesn't work:

```
void touch_begin_gesture(float x, float y) {

    /**
     * create a new empty Quartz event
     */
    CGEventRef begin_gesture_event = CGEventCreate(NULL);

    /**
     * fill created Quartz event
     */
    CGEventSetType(begin_gesture_event, TouchEventTypeBeginGesture);
    CGEventSetLocation(begin_gesture_event, CGPointMake(x, y));

    /**
     * post a Quartz event into the event stream at a specified location.
     */
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, begin_gesture_event);

    /**
     * release Quartz event
     */
    CFRelease(begin_gesture_event);
}

void touch_end_gesture(float x, float y) {

    /**
     * create a new empty Quartz event
     */
    CGEventRef end_gesture_event = CGEventCreate(NULL);

    /**
     * fill created Quartz event
     */
    CGEventSetType(end_gesture_event, TouchEventTypeEndGesture);
    CGEventSetLocation(end_gesture_event, CGPointMake(x, y));

    /**
     * post a Quartz event into the event stream at a specified location.
     */
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, end_gesture_event);

    /**
     * release Quartz event
     */
    CFRelease(end_gesture_event);
}

void touch_pinch_gesture_at(float magnification, float x, float y) {

    /**
     * create a new empty Quartz event
     */
    CGEventRef magnify_gesture_event = CGEventCreate(NULL);

    /**
     * fill created Quartz event
     */
    CGEventSetType(magnify_gesture_event, TouchEventTypeMagnify);
    CGEventSetLocation(magnify_gesture_event, CGPointMake(x, y));

    /**
     * post a Quartz event into the event stream at a specified location.
     */
    CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, magnify_gesture_event);

    /**
     * release Quartz event
     */
    CFRelease(magnify_gesture_event);
}
```

And here are constants:

```
enum {
    TouchEventTypeGesture = 29,
    TouchEventTypeMagnify = 30, // pinch
    TouchEventTypeSwipe = 31,   // swipe
    TouchEventTypeRotate = 18,  // rotate
    TouchEventTypeBeginGesture = 19,
    TouchEventTypeEndGesture = 20,
    TouchEventTypeSmartMagnify = 32,
    TouchEventTypeQuickLook = 33,
    TouchEventTypePressure = 34
};

void touch_begin_gesture(float x, float y);
void touch_end_gesture(float x, float y);
void touch_pinch_gesture(float magnification);
void touch_pinch_gesture_at(float magnification, float x, float y);
```

And I use this invocations:

```
int main() {

    touch_begin_gesture(350, 350);

    touch_pinch_gesture_at(1.5, 400, 400);

    touch_end_gesture(450, 450);

    return 0;
}
```

I consider how is such touch events generation possible? How can I set this magnification, rotation, swipe direction values. Is anywhere documentation to it? Anyone have tried to achieve this? I found on stackoverflow similar question but without correct answer and rather older. Can I achieve this in clear C language without Objective-C?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I thinkt it should be clear I want to post touch gesture event in Cocoa on OS X system. I place creation of 3 events begin gesture event, magnify gesture event, end gesture event. I want to achieve pinch (magnify) gesture simulation on OS X with cocoa what here isn't clear? If I am posting peoples write paste all code not some it parts